# comparing pandas dataframe with sqlite table via sqlquery

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I have a sqlite database with the below columns, and 1000 rows

```
con.execute('CREATE TABLE "table" (Fruit TEXT, Texture TEXT, Code TEXT, Buy TEXT )'
```

I want to compare a `pandas.Dataframe` with this `table`, and if the value in the column `sqlite "Code"` **is not** in `df['Code']`, then update `sqlite "Buy"` with the word "Yes".

Initially I tried using the below code to see if I can get all the results from `df['Code']` to print if it exists, then I could just add in a `NOT` into the `sqlite query` to flip the results, but currently, the below code prints out 1000 rows of empty lists, and occasionally prints out some of the `Code` instead...

```
for each_code in df['Code']:
    z = con.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "table" WHERE Code IN ({c}))'
                     .format(c=each_code)).fetchall()
    print(z)
```

Not sure where my error lies? I thought of doing this at the database level since it might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have the following SQLite table:

```
sqlite> select * from tab;
Fruit       Texture     Code        Buy
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
apple                   code1
orange                  code2
mango                   code3
banana                  code4
peach                   code5
```

and the following DF:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
    Code
0  code1
1  code3
2  code5
3  code7
```

I'd do it in the following way:

first save DF into the same SQLite file with a different table name:

```
import sqlite3    
con = sqlite3.connect('d:/temp/a.db')    
df.to_sql('tmp', con, index=False)
```

Result (SQLite):

```
sqlite> select * from tmp;
Code
----------
code1
code3
code5
code7
```

now we can efficiently update our `tab` table directly in the SQLite:

```
sqlite> update tab set buy='Yes' where not exists (select 1 from tmp where tmp.code=tab.code);
sqlite> select * from tab;
Fruit       Texture     Code        Buy
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
apple                   code1
orange                  code2       Yes
mango                   code3
banana                  code4       Yes
peach                   code5
```

Of course you can do the last step in Python:

```
con.execute("update tab set buy='Yes' where not exists (select 1 from tmp where tmp.code=tab.code)")
# optional clean up
con.execute("drop table tmp")
con.commit()
```